# HttpRequest (PHP to C#) - deserialize a string

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to send a string to a C# app via php, here is my code:

PHP

```
//set up variables
$theData = 'test
to see if a string can be deserialized';
$url = 'http://localhost:5900/';
//create the httprequest object                
$httpRequest_OBJ = new httpRequest($url, HTTP_METH_POST, $options);
//add the raw post data
$httpRequest_OBJ->setRawPostData ($theData);
//send the http request
$result = $httpRequest_OBJ->send();

//get the object
$response = $result->getBody();
```

C#

Here is where it fails:

```
var methodRequestSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MethodRequest));
            var methodRequest = methodRequestSerializer.Deserialize(reader) as MethodRequest;
```

PHP throws back the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'HttpInvalidParamException' with message 'Empty or too short HTTP message: ''' in C:\xampp\htdocs\httpreq.php:39 inner exception 'HttpRequestException' with message 'server returned nothing (no headers, no data); Empty reply from server (http://localhost:5900/)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\httpreq.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\httpreq.php(39): HttpRequest->send() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\httpreq.php on line 39

thanks.

Comment: Is it normal that you send you data not to a ASPX/ASHX file?

Comment: Is there anyway I could send the data directly to the C# app, and then get it to deseralize the data on the fly?

Comment: Where does your C# `reader` come from?

Comment: Well if you want to send data to C# you need to do it via somewhere. If you want to send it to an ASP page than you need to modify you URL. you cannot just submit your data to the server IP and hope that something will be done with IIS. I think before doing stuff like playing with PHP-ASP that you should try to master both of them a little bit more and get some information about how website works.

Comment: Chris - reader comes from the input stream:

 var request = context.Request;
            var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream);
             
            var methodRequestSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MethodRequest));
            var methodRequest = methodRequestSerializer.Deserialize(reader) as MethodRequest;

Daok, I have managed to successfully send the data to the C# app via the input stream, as the string appears on the console, it just fails when  being serialized.

Answer (score 0):

When you say your `reader` comes from `new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream)`, I'm assuming that `context` is the ASP.NET `HttpContext` object, and your C# code is somehow deployed so as to receive an HttpRequest.

If so, the stream will contain just the bytes from the body of your HTTP request, which in the case of your example will just be the string "test to see if a string can be deserialized". Since this is not valid XML you should expect the `Deserialize` method call to fail.

You haven't told us what `MethodRequest` is, nor what an instance would look like when XML serialized. If the string you sent in the HTTP POST request were a valid XML-serialized instance of MethodRequest, I would expect your C# `Deserialize` method call to succeed.

If you'd be a little less coy and share fuller details of what you're trying to do and how, we might be able to help more easily.